# Variable at start of list not defined

Tags: python

I am having a problem with whatever variable is first in the list. For example, if the list began with a, it throws a NameError, and when it starts with b, it too throws a name error. I am absolutely baffled by this and I would appreciate any insights.

NOTE: This is a generalised version of my program as I wanted to keep it relevant to others. There are many variables in my full program, so that's why I am importing them separately (aesthetics).

The main program

```
import variables

variables = [a, b, c]

with open('/Users/bendowling/USER_INPUT.txt', 'r') as UserInputFile:
    UserInput = UserInputFile.read()
    UserInput = UserInput.strip()
    UserInput = UserInput.lower()

UserInputFile = open('/Users/bendowling/USER_INPUT.txt', 'w+')

for vars in variables:
    if vars in UserInput:
        UserInputFile.write("%s", vars)

UserInputFile.close()
```

The variables (i.e. variables.py)

```
a = ["something1", "something2", "something3"]

b = ["something4", "something5", "something6"]

c = ["something7", "something8", "something9"]
```

Comment: Where is a,b,c and commands from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're importing the `variables` module qualified, so to get at `a`, `b`, and `c`, you'll need to qualify them as `variables.a`, `variables.b`, etc. Alternatively, you can import it as

```
from variables import a, b, c
```